# Matrix sequence limit convergence

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, normed-spaces

Let $A_k$ be a sequence of matrices such that $\lim A_kx=Ax$ for all $x\in \mathbb{R}^n$. Then I need to prove that $A_k \rightarrow A$ with respect to any norm.

Comment: One approach is to use the condition given to show that the entries of $A_k$ converge to the entries of $A$.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom I thought about that, however I wanted to find a way to formally prove the limit with $\epsilon$

Comment: You should probably try proving the result for a specific matrix norm if you want to deal with $\epsilon$s.  The Frobenius norm is usually nice for these things.  You can then extend the result using the (topological) equivalence of norms on finite dimensional spaces.

Comment: Ah, yes, I think I got it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key result here is that any two norms on the same finite dimensional space are equivalent. Hence it is sufficient to show the result for a specific (and
convenient) norm.

Define $\|A\|_* = \sum_i \|A e_i\|$, where $e_i$ are the standard basis vectors. It is easy to check that this is a norm, and since
$\|A-A_k\|_* = \sum_k \|(A-A_k)e_i\|$, we see that $\|A-A_k\|_* \to 0$.

Answer (score 2):

Since for every basic vector with have the mentioned convergence, we have that the entries on $A_k=(a^k_{i,j})$ must converge to the entries on $A = (a_{i,j})$. Take $|A| = \max|a_{i,j}|$.
Then there exists $K>0$ such that for all $k>K$, $|a^k_{i,j}-a_{i,j}|<\epsilon $ for all $i,j$ (since there are finitely many).
So, for $k>K$, we have 
$$|A_k-A| = \max |a^k_{i,j}-a_{i,j}| <\epsilon$$